# Python Selenium. Получение дочерних тэгов

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Прошу помощи. Не могу понять, можем ли мы провалиться с помощью `find_elemets_by_` глубже в код? Например, есть следующий код:

```
<div class="element">
   <li class="first_name"> Иван </li>
   <li class="second_name"> Иванов </li>
</div>

<div class="element">
   <li class="first_name"> Петр </li>
   <li class="second_name"> Петров </li>
</div>

<div class="element">
   <li class="first_name"> Александр </li>
   <li class="second_name"> Александров </li>
</div>
```

Если мы попытаемся взять элементЫ по классу `find_elemets_by_class_name("element")`, то получим три веб.элемента. Чтобы я хотел, но не знаю, как получить.
Я хочу пробежаться по полученному списку веб.элементов обратиться к каждому и сказать, дай мне то, что у тебя там будет дальше в классе first_name, а может дай мне то, что у тебя там дальше в a/href/div/li и пр. и т.д. Может быть можно взять второй find_element?
ниже псевдокод

```
list_elem = driver.find_elemets_by_class_name("element")

for each_elem in list_elem:
     each_elem.ДАЙ_МНЕ_FIRST_NAME
     each_elem.ДАЙ_МНЕ_LAST_NAME
```

Есть ли возможность обратиться к веб.элементу и обратиться уже к дочерним его тэгам? 
Дабы потом, создать некий словарь.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос закрываю.

Да, моя догадка была верна, мы можем обратиться к "найденному" элементу, и искать уже "внутри" него. Т.е. для моего условного примера, каждый элемент `each_elem` будет иметь внутри себя структуру:

```
<li class="first_name"> ____</li>
<li class="second_name"> ____ </li>
```

условно говоря, из всего "большого сайта", мы теперь обращаемся только к "дочерним тэгам", которые есть у  `each_elem`

И для примера, мы сможем обратиться вот так

```
each_elem.find_elements_by_class_name("first_name").text
each_elem.find_elements_by_class_name("second_name").text
```

И получим значения для каждого `each_elem`

Надеюсь, кому-то это может пригодиться)